# Regex to find alpha&numeric words in a text

Tags: python, regex

I've got this text:

```
due to previous assess c6c587469 and 4ec0f198
nearest and with fill station in the citi
becaus of our satisfact in the d4a29a already
averaging my thoughts on e977f33588f react to
```

and I want to remove all "alpha&numeric" words

In output, I want

```
due to previous assess and 
nearest and with fill station in the citi
becaus of our satisfact in the already
averaging my thoughts on react to
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work..

```
df_colum = df_colum.str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+', '')
```

Any regex expert ?

Thanks

Comment: Try [`(?i)\b(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])\w+\b *`](https://regex101.com/r/bCLjww/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
df_colum = df_colum.str.replace('\w*\d\w*', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way without regex:

```
def parser(x):
    return ' '.join([i for i in x.split() if not any(c.isdigit() for c in i)])

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(parser)

print(df)

                                        text
0                 due to previous assess and
1  nearest and with fill station in the citi
2     becaus of our satisfact in the already
3          averaging my thoughts on react to
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
df_colum = df_colum.str.replace('(?:[0-9][^ ]*[A-Za-z][^ ]*)|(?:[A-Za-z][^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*)', '')
```

Explanation of the regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/iI3vX2/1#testarea)

Answer (score 0):

You can look for where a digit meets a letter `\d[a-z]` or `[a-z]\d` then match up to end:

```
(?i)\b(?:[a-z]+\d+|\d+[a-z]+)\w*\b *
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOFon7/1)

- `(?i)` Enables case-insensitivity
- `(?:...)` Constructs a non-capturing group
- `\b` Means a word boundary

Python code:

```
re.sub(r"\b(?:[a-z]+\d+|\d+[a-z]+)\w*\b *", "", str)
```